# How to copy all data from unmountable corrupted harddrive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

My wifes computers hard drive effectively died. All write operation fail and active time is constantly 100%. Drive is currently unmounted as to not slow down the entire system, but still active time shows 100%.

Is there a way for to copy all the data from the unmounted drive to another drive without having to create a backup or mount the drive? Since writing is slow/not working there are many operations that cannot be done.

Or can I mount the drive in such a way that the data related to mounting is stored on another drive?

PC runs on Windows 10.

---

**Update**: I got a Ddrescue for Windows (it run through Linux virtual machine). Weird thing happened. Active time is now on 50% not 100%. I have a feeling that there is some application on the drive that will suck up the read/write on it when I try to acces the drive. but I dont know what it might be. My best guess ATM is Epic Games as it was already getting slower  and slower to run.

Once Ddrescue complete I will see what happens on the new drive. If same thing happens, then I need to start to remove apps from the drive somehow

---

**Update**: Using ddrescue a complete copy of the disk was made on another HDD. Everything works fine now. No data was lost, beside some icon links.

Some things I noticed during the rescue process. Once I opened the computer with the faulty drive connected. Active time was 0%. I immediately opened ddrescue and got to working. During the entire clone/copy process activity never spiked over 65%. No bad sectors were found. My assumption is that the read/write heads were fine and the disks themselves are all good, but the controller of the drive was getting errors either from drivers or physical which causes it to go into some endless loop when trying to directly access it through Windows.

Comment: The drive is dead. I assume you don’t have backups?

Comment: No backups. It is tehcnically accessible. If i mount it. its just super slow

Comment: My suggestion. Get yourself a HDD duplication device. It’s your best chance to get the data of a disk behaving the way you describe

Comment: Made my sort-of suggestion in the answers, though that's mostly for geeks. I don't know if there is a GUI tool for data recovery, but I think it would be more useful for the general case.

Comment: A consumer HDD duplication device such as a docking station assumably lacks the abilities of ddrescue and will most likely duplicate the disk in a linear fashion. If the source disk has lots of pending sectors using such a device will stress the source and recover in an inefficient way - wasting time on erroneous zones although lots of readable sectors are available elsewhere.

Comment: there's different levels of dead. If its hardware going kaput you're out of luck. I've had a drive mount fine in linux and I was able to do a file level copy. There's everything in between.

Comment: You need to stop experimenting with it. Recovery should be attempted after you have made up mind about strategy. Disk cloning / imaging should be done with drive connected to native port, not go though USB or virtual machines etc.. Get SMART to get some idea about disk health.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux world has a tool called [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue) for recovering data from near-dead drives. You only need to boot into a Linux installation disk to use it – you don't need to install Linux from there.

The [SystemRescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/) distribution comes with `ddrescue` on its ISOs. Burn the ISOs on a CD or [a USB thumb drive](https://www.system-rescue.org/Installing-SystemRescue-on-a-USB-memory-stick/), then reboot into the CD/USB thumb drive to gain access to `ddrescue`.

`ddrescue`'s basic usage is as follows. Ensure `/dev/sdx` is the bad disk with all your precious data, and that `/dev/sdy` is a good disk larger than `/dev/sdx` (Thanks [Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski)):

```
# ddrescue /dev/sdx /dev/sdy data.map
```

You may need to fix `/dev/sdy`'s partition table and run checks (`fsck` or `CHKDSK`) on each partition after recovering.

Note that its usage requires some Linux knowledge and command-line basics. There is no drive letter like in Windows, and you have to name your hard drive as something like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/nvme0`. If you are unsure which is the bad drive, you can use `lsblk` to get a clue.

Comment: *And then what?* Will Windows 10 be able to do anything useful with `data.img`? How to proceed? For average Joe a better choice may be to rescue directly to a block device, because there's a chance the target device will "just work" in Windows. There are pitfalls and edge cases even then.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski My own workflow, sort of. Edited.

Comment: I vaguely recall that windows has *some* image mounting abilities since 10, else the tools you need to mount it are in linux

Comment: @JourneymanGeek At least ISO9660 as far as I can recall. Probably also FAT. Likely not MBR or GPT images which can contain multiple partitions.

Comment: And then what: Then you can try mount disk image but often you'd need to use a file recovery tool that can work with a sector by sector disk image, examples UFS Explorer, DMDE ..

Answer (score 1):

assuming this is a rotating disk drive, likely the more the drive is used, the more it will get damaged. (there is an avalanche failure mode due to... reasons.) so do not power it while it is not being rescued.

you can try rescuing it: you need a place to store the rescued contents (space in a disk for a file as big as the failing disk. you could also use a new disk at least as big as the old one, but you still need another disk to store some extra files.)

1. first download and flash a live linux distro image to a pendrive. i recommend linux mint cinnamon.
2. check that you can boot linux mint.
3. power off, connect the failing drive and rescue destination drive(s) to the PC, then reboot linux mint.
4. use the "Disks" application to check that all drives are visible to the PC.
5. i assume you do not have linux swap partitions in the failing disk (you were not using linux before). but if you do, use "Disks" to unmount/stop the swap partitions there.
6. open a terminal and type `ddrescue` to check if ddrescue is installed. if not, connect to the internet then type `sudo apt install gddrescue` to install it, then retry.
7. follow some ddrescue how-to, such as this one: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-repair-and-clone-disk-with-ddrescue

notes:

- ddrescue produces two outputs: a backup of the readable parts of the disk, and a log specifying which areas could be read and which could not.
- it may take almost forever to backup a failing drive: the more damage, the more time.
- when the backup is done, you will need to reconstruct the readable parts of the disk into useful data. (some tools help: ddrescueview, ddrutility, etc. you can install them with `sudo apt install ...`.)
- but forget about magic: most data could be lost already.

good luck!

Comment: recovered all data :)